# How to read file from HTML file input as ReadableStream?

Tags: javascript, stream

I have code that runs through a text file using `ReadableStream` and finds some log lines in it. This works for me currently with the `fetch` API and `FileHandle.readableWebStream` on the Node.js backend.

The code is based in this code on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#processing_a_text_file_line_by_line):

```
async function* makeTextFileLineIterator(fileURL) {
  const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
  const response = await fetch(fileURL);
  const reader = response.body.getReader();
  let { value: chunk, done: readerDone } = await reader.read();
  chunk = chunk ? utf8Decoder.decode(chunk) : "";

  const newline = /\r?\n/gm;
  let startIndex = 0;
  let result;

  while (true) {
    const result = newline.exec(chunk);
    if (!result) {
      if (readerDone) break;
      const remainder = chunk.substr(startIndex);
      ({ value: chunk, done: readerDone } = await reader.read());
      chunk = remainder + (chunk ? utf8Decoder.decode(chunk) : "");
      startIndex = newline.lastIndex = 0;
      continue;
    }
    yield chunk.substring(startIndex, result.index);
    startIndex = newline.lastIndex;
  }

  if (startIndex < chunk.length) {
    // Last line didn't end in a newline char
    yield chunk.substr(startIndex);
  }
}
```

<sup>I made some alterations, but this should be sufficient as an example for the people that always require a question has some code in it.</sup>

I'd also like be able to parse this log file directly from HTML `file` input. I want to avoid reading the entire file in memory, because these files can be up to 3 GB, and all I need to do is to find individual log lines.

How to convert files from file inputs to `ReadableStream` and read them chunk by chunk instead of all at once?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is actually very easy, I just couldn't find the right search query to find it:

```
        const fileInput = main.querySelector("input.fileread");
        const file = fileInput.files[0];
        const stream = file.stream();
        // usefull for displaying progress
        const expectedSize = file.size;
     
        const reader = stream.getReader();
```